# jQuery UI dialog not centred on iPad

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've an issue with a jQuery UI dialog which is opening a video on iPad.

It works fine on all browsers on all platforms except iPad where it won't center the dialog. It shows at 0,0.

The site is www.rainforestretreat.co.nz and you can see the issue by clicking the video link in the left nav.

I am triggering the dialog and starting the video with:

```
$(".fancyBox").click(function(){
                $("#video").dialog({
                    height:500,
                    width:800,
                    open: function(event, ui){
                        $('#overlay').fadeIn();
                        _V_("RRVideo").ready(function(){
                            var myPlayer = this;
                            myPlayer.play();
                        });
                    },
                    close: function(event, ui){
                        $('.ui-dialog').hide();
                        $('#overlay').fadeOut();
                        _V_("RRVideo").ready(function(){
                            var myPlayer = this;
                            myPlayer.pause();
                        });
                    },
                    show: 'fade'
                });
                return false;
            });
```

I have tried adding position:'center' as an option but this does not make a difference. (When I position top and bottom, other browsers reflect the change but no change is made on iPad).

Has anyone come accross this before?

Comment: may be a bug. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ipad-and-jquery-dialog

Comment: How are you testing? Maybe try using Safari and mimic the iPad User Agent (via Development Tools) so you can then use other development tools to get more info about the elements.

Comment: That's a decent idea. I had it flagged to me by an iPad user and I've been testing it on xcode's iOs simulator.